# How to use jqplot charts in a jquery mobile web app

Tags: jquery, mobile, jqplot

I want to create charts in jQuery mobile web app. I am using `jqPlot` charts but I am unable to create charts. 
I am using the following code:

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/app/jquery.mobile-1.0b2.min.js")"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript"src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.jqplot.min.js")"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/jquery.jqplot.min.css" )"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/jquery.mobile-1.0b2.css")" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/jquery.mobile-1.0b2.min.css")" />

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $('#index').live('pageinit', function (event) {
                alert("jqplotchart");
                $.jqplot('container', [[[1, 2], [3, 5.12], [5, 13.1], [7, 33.6], [9, 85.9], [11, 219.9]]]);
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="index" data-role="page">
            <div id="container" style="height: 400px; min-width: 600px">
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

To check the jQuery I also added an alert in the function but it is not showing the alert also. Maybe because I am using the `pageinit()` event in the wrong way? Please suggest me how to use the `pageinit()` event or do I need to use other events to create the charts?

Answer (score 0):

This probably doesn't need an answer any more, but if I'd seen the question a few days ago I'd have found the answer useful.

There are two problems:

1. You need to include 'jquery.mobile-x.x.x.min.js' before you include the jquery mobile javascript.
2. jqPlot doesn't like 'pageinit'.  You need to use 'pageshow' instead.

Answer (score 0):

**There is an easier way (worked in my case):**

-**first:** delare your *plot container div* outside of any page (for example just below *body* tag):

```
<body>
<div id="plotContainer"></div>
...
```

-**then:** set the plot (Chart) in your *$(document).ready(function(){ ... **here** ... });* and hide it so it will not show between pages:

```
$("#jqxChart").jqxChart(settings);
$("#jqxChart").hide();
```

-**finaly:** just copy the div with the plot inside your page:

```
<script>
$('#page_ID').bind('pageshow', function(data) { 
$("#jqxChart").appendTo("#ID_of_DIV_you_want");
$("#jqxChart").show();  
$('#jqxChart').jqxChart('refresh');
});
</script>
```

Hope this helps!!!